# How to browse android gallery for movie/media files in SDK

Tags: android-emulator, android, directory-browsing

Can anybody tell me how to browse for a movie file from the android folders (either phone/SD Card memory). Let's say I got a movie file on the phone memory and I want to access it from my application, what is the best way to do it?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use

Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MEDIA_SEARCH);

I'm not sure but I hope this put you in the right track

here the link for this class

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#INTENT_ACTION_MEDIA_SEARCH